# how to create a generic method with optional generic parameter in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, optional-parameters, generic-list

I have created a generic method with out parameter in c#. it will return two out parameter value  which I pass list object .

```
public void ExecuteList<T, T1>(out List<T> obj, out List<T1> obj1, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
{
    using (var db = _context)
    {
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        try
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            using (var reder = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                obj = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reder).ToList();
                reder.NextResult();
                obj1 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T1>(reder).ToList();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method

```
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>(); 
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageNo", 1));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize", 5)); 
SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();
List<PostModel> PostList = new List<PostModel>();
List<Tag> TagList = new List<Tag>();
Uow.ExecuteList<PostModel,Tag>(out PostList, out TagList, "[dbo].[sp_getdata]", parameters);
```

Here I pass postmodel and tag class for casting and also pass two out parameter  PostList and TagList for result.
It will return perfect result.
But my requirement is these casting classes and out parameters should be optional.
Like this:
When I want one Result then pass one casting class and one Out parameter.

```
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageNo", 1));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize", 5)); 
SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();
List<PostModel> PostList = new List<PostModel>(); 
Uow.ExecuteList<PostModel>(out PostList, "[dbo].[sp_getdata]", parameters);
```

And when I want two Result then pass two casting class and two out parameter.

```
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageNo", 1));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pageSize", 5)); 
SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();
List<PostModel> PostList = new List<PostModel>();
List<Tag> TagList = new List<Tag>();
Uow.ExecuteList<PostModel,Tag>(out PostList, out TagList, "[dbo].[sp_getdata]", parameters);
```

Please help me to solve my issue

Comment: You're trying to replicate what Entity Framework already provides. Which EF version are you using? The problem is the attempt to use plain old ADO.NET and mapping in the first place. There are ways to map stored procedure results to entities already.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You have a problem `X` (how to map a stored procedure to entities) and assume that `Y` is the solution (write plain old ADO.NET code). When you hit a problem (*lots* of manual code needed for mapping) you ask about Y, not the actual problem, X

Comment: There are other serious problems with this code too - it's passing `1` as the *type* of  the type of `@pageNo`. The constructor called in this code is [SqlParameter(string,SqlDbType )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_). That's because enums are essentially ints. Besides, *paging* is already available through eg `Products.....Skip().Take()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create several overloads which will call the same private method:

```
private void Execute<T, T1>(ref List<T> obj, ref List<T1> obj1, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
{
    using (var db = _context)
    {    
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        try
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                obj = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader).ToList();
                if(obj1 != null) {
                    reader.NextResult();
                    obj1 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T1>(reader).ToList();
                }                
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public void ExecuteList<T, T1>(out List<T> obj, out List<T1> obj1, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
{
    obj = new List<T>();
    obj1 = new List<T1>();
    Execute(ref obj, ref obj1, sql, parameters);
}

public void ExecuteList<T>(out List<T> obj, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
{
    obj = new List<T>();
    List<object> stub = null;//generic argument doesn't matter because it will not be used
    Execute<T, object>(ref obj, ref stub, sql, parameters);
}
```

Note that my first method is private and should be called only from public overloads(it's possible to add as many output parameters/overloads as you wish).

Also probably it makes sense to restrict `T1` to `class` as well and use `List<SqlParameter>` instead of `params object[] parameters` as a last parameter.

Comment: EF already provides ways to map stored procedures to entities.

Comment: it is not useful for me , because i don't want overloaded method. please give me any solution without overloaded method if possible. and all parameter should be optional.

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: this was very useful to me! I had two generic parameters where the first must be based on the second, but the second is optional. `protected static IMyInterface DoSomething<T, T2>(IList<T> data, MySpecialDelegate<T2> mySpecialFunction = null) where T : T2`